# Easiest way to select a v-for item from dom by property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I am rendering a list of deals like so:

```
<deal :deal="deal"
      v-for="(deal, index) in deals"
      :key="index"
      ref="deals"
      @click.native="setScrollLocation(deal.id)">
</deal>
```

Now a deal has an `id` property as you can see that is being passed into the `setScrollLocation` method.

How can I select the element with the specific deal id from the dom?

I could use something like a data-attribute and simply set the deal id on it like so:

```
<deal :data-deal-id="deal.id"></deal>
```

Now I have something that could be queried with a `document.querySelector` by using something like `this.$el.querySelector`.

I prefer not to use something like a `querySelector` within my component because this is not fault tolerant. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe a directive that creates a mapping from `id` to element. Or manage such a mapping from the `mounted` and `beforeDestroy` hooks of the component.

Comment: @RoyJ Care to elaborate? I am also wondering if the `ref` property can be set to the `deal.id` or something. This would allow me to select it from the `$refs` element I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your component [`emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)s an event in its `mounted` [hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) and another in its `beforeDestroy` hook, the parent can use them to maintain a mapping from `id` to element.

```
mounted() {
  this.$emit('mapElement', deal.id, this.$el);
}

beforeDestroy() {
  this.$emit('unmapElement', deal.id);
}
```

The parent would have something like

```
methods: {
  mapElement(id, el) {
    this.elementMap[id] = el;
  },
  unmapElement(id) {
    delete this.elementMap[id];
  }
}
```

and would hook them up like

```
<deal :deal="deal"
      v-for="(deal, index) in deals"
      :key="index"
      ref="deals"
      @mapElement="mapElement"
      @unmapElement="unmapElement">
</deal>
```

Then when you need the element associated with a deal id, it's in `this.elementMap[id]`.

Comment: Damn, that is one clever solution. I am going to try this out.